# Unable to remove table row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove table row, data is deleted from database but why it is not removed from html table.
Any solution appreciated!

```
 $('#datatables').on('click', '.delete_department', (e) => {
        var id = e.currentTarget.id;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: BASE_URL + 'admin/delete_department',
            data: { id: id },
            success: (response) => {
                $('#datatables').closest('tr').remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the HTML Table that is generated using PHP

```html
<table id="datatables" class="css-serial text-center table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover dataTable dtr-inline">
  <thead>
      <tr role="row">
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Department</th>
          <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
      <tr>
          <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">#</th>
          <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Department</th>
          <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Action</th>
      </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($departments  as $key => $department) { ?>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <p data-letters="<?php echo ucwords(substr($department['department'], 0, 1)); ?>"></p>
              </td>
              <td><?php echo $department['department'] ?></td>
              <td>
                  <button class='edit_department btn btn-danger btn-link' id='<?php echo $department['id'] ?>'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button>
                  <button class='delete_department btn btn-danger btn-link' id='<?php echo $department['id'] ?>'><i class='material-icons'>close</i></button>
              </td>
          </tr>
      <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add `html` table structue

Comment: I guess ` $('#datatables')` refer to `<table>` tag and using closest to find `tr` will not work.

Comment: @AswinKumar check the new update.

Comment: @RobinSingh you have to check whether deleted row appears while searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the reference of clicked button element and then use `closest` to get `tr`.

```
$('#datatables').on('click', '.delete_department', function(e) {
    const that = $(this);
    var id = e.currentTarget.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: BASE_URL + 'admin/delete_department',
        data: { id: id }, // or just use shorthand notation { id }
        success: (response) => {
            $(that).closest('tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Note - Instead of arrow function, use `function()` to get the reference of clicked element.

Comment: @AswinKumar can u explain what u trying to say

Comment: @RobinSingh search for the deleted row's department in `datatables` search box or sort any column, then the deleted row will appear

Comment: @AswinKumar yes, this was just an example. i already code for check deleted row

Comment: @RobinSingh why not a straightforward approach as  in my solution?